# Woocomerce как исключить (спрятать) товары из каталога магазина и результата поиска?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Допустим, у нас есть такая функция:

```
must_be_hide($post_id) {
  $bool = in_array($post_id, array(1, 2, 3, 4 ,5));
  return $bool;
}
```

Как при помощи такой функции скрыть продукты из каталога (query) и из результатов поиска? В сети находил - как спрятать категорию товаров, а как скрыть продукты по id не могу понять...

Comment: Почитайте тут http://wp-kama.ru/hook/pre_get_posts . Для изменения id нужно изменить параметр поста: http://wp-kama.ru/function/wp_query#parametry-postov-i-stranits

Comment: @Ponio - спасибо, по следам указанных вами материалов удалось написать код.

Comment: Очень хорошо :)

Answer (score 2):

Ок, спасибо Ponio - код для того чтобы прятать товары по id выглядит как-то так:

```
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'hide_from_query' );
function hide_from_query($q) {

    // id товаров которые нужно прятать
    $exclude_ids = array(18, 24);

        // Если это не админ и не карточка товара
        if ( ! $q->is_main_query() || is_admin() || is_single()) { 
            return;
        }

        if ( $exclude_ids ) {

            $taxquery = array(
                array(
                    'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
                    'field'    => 'id',                     
                    'operator' => 'NOT IN'
                ) 
            );

            $q->set( 'tax_query', $taxquery );

            /*
            // Раскоментируй если хочешь прятать карточку товара

            if ( is_single() ) {
                $q->set( 'post__not_in', $exclude_ids );
                return;
            }
            */
            $q->set( 'post__not_in', $exclude_ids );
        }

        return;
}
```

Это работает и для результатов поиска.